# TPL Async Await in Console Apps

Tags: c#, async-await

I just picked up Async Await and I am trying to use Async Await in Console App along with TPL for querying webservices. The code works fine and I am able to get the speed using HttpClient and async. Wanted to know if I am overusing async/await and if there is anything that I should avoid and can be simplified further.

I have read Albahari's threading e-book and the following articles to understand the usage.

http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/how-and-where-concurrent-asynchronous-io-with-asp-net-web-api

https://web.archive.org/web/20160718142900/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/01/13/10115163.aspx

https://scalablenotions.wordpress.com/2015/05/02/tpl-and-async-await-best-practices-for-the-busy-developer/

```
class Program
{
    public class Member
    {
        public string N { get; set; }
        public string E { get; set; }
    }


    static void Main()
    {
        List<Member> list = new List<Member>();
        Task.Run(async () => { await SubscribeMembersusingAPI(list); }).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    }

    // Define other methods and classes here
    public static async Task SubscribeMembersusingAPI(List<Member> members)
    {
        List<string> updateemailstosubscribed = new List<string>();
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        try
        {
            await Task.WhenAll(members.Select(m => SubscribeusingAPI(client, m)));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //logger.Error("Error in Async task", e);
        }
        return;
    }

    public static async Task<bool> SubscribeusingAPI(HttpClient client, Member member)
    {
        try
        {
            List<KeyValuePair<String, String>> listkvp = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
            listkvp.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("e", member.E.Trim()));
            listkvp.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("n", member.N.Trim()));
            listkvp.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("boolean", "true"));
            FormUrlEncodedContent formpost = new FormUrlEncodedContent(listkvp);
            var response = await client.PostAsync("", formpost);
            string responsebody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            if (responsebody == "1" || responsebody == "Member present")
                return true;
            else
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("FAIL, Error while subscribing e: {0}, n: {1}, response: {2}", member.E, member.N, responsebody));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("FAIL, Error while subscribing e: {0}, n: {1} ", member.E, member.N), e);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Let’s try to apply [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), and get rid of mutable state to increase code maintainability. It inflates C# code a little bit, but usually makes sense.

Demo:

```
  IEnumerable<Member> members = new Member[] { new Member("n","e") };
  await members
      .SubscribeAsync()
      .LogAsync(Console.Out);
```

Where `Member` could be immutable:

```
public class Member
{
    public Member(string n, string e)
    {
        N = n.Trim();
        E = e.Trim();
    }

    public string N { get; }
    public string E { get; }
    public override string ToString() => $"N={N}, E={E}";
}
```

We will use this universal helper class to log task exceptions:

```
static class Logging
{
    public static async Task LogAsync(this Task task, TextWriter writer)
    {
        try
        {
            await task;
        }            
        catch (AggregateException ex)
        {
            foreach (var exx in ex.Flatten().InnerExceptions)
                await writer.WriteLineAsync(exx.Message);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            await writer.WriteLineAsync(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Now subscription helpers:

```
static class Subscription
{
    public static Task SubscribeAsync(this IEnumerable<Member> members) =>
        Task.WhenAll(from member in members
                     select member.SubscribeAsync());

    public static Task<SubscriptionResponse> SubscribeAsync(this Member member) =>
        new SubscriptionRequest(member).ExecuteAsync();
}
```

Subscription request:

```
public class SubscriptionRequest
{
    const string RequestUrl = "";

    public SubscriptionRequest(Member member)
    {
        Member = member;
    }

    public async Task<SubscriptionResponse> ExecuteAsync()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
            try
            {
                var response = await client.PostAsync(RequestUrl, Content);
                var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return new SubscriptionResponse(responseBody);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw new SubscriptionException(Member, ex);
            }            
    }

    FormUrlEncodedContent Content => new FormUrlEncodedContent(Kvps);
    IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Kvps => new[]
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("e", Member.E),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("n", Member.N),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("boolean", "true")
    };

    Member Member { get; } 
}
```

And response:

```
public class SubscriptionResponse
{
    public SubscriptionResponse(string body)
    {
        Body = body;
        if (!Success)
            throw new InvalidOperationException(body);
    }

    public bool Subscribed => Body == "1";
    public bool AlreadySubscribed => Body == "Member present";
    bool Success => Subscribed || AlreadySubscribed;
    string Body { get; }
}
```

The only missing part:

```
public class SubscriptionException : Exception
{
    public SubscriptionException(Member member, Exception error) :
        base($"{member} subscription failed, error: {error.Message}", error)
    {
    }
}
```

P.S. Generally speaking, C# is a pretty verbose language, so it is often punishing good programming practices…

Comment: Thats really a good structure, liked the abstraction and helper methods. Appreciate it. Could you also comment more specifically on async/await, et al.

Comment: I would use [AsyncContext](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-console-programs.html) from Nito.AsyncEx NuGet package - it will take care about many things for you. [Concurrency in C# Cookbook](https://books.google.com/books?id=nsaUAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA72&lpg=PA72&dq=nito+new+asynccontext&source=bl&ots=tNLNNVzEoH&sig=FNfYPl0Qk6aKCT82J_3v3xT48Vk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_r97mkKDNAhVSLlIKHUI0BKEQ6AEIMjAH#v=onepage&q=nito&f=false) discusses it.

Comment: Had read about it, but since it needed a seperate binary felt using from what is available, can give it a try and see. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short example why `Nito AsyncEx` could be useful. Let’s try execute the following code:

```
    static Task MainAsync(string[] args)
    {
        return Task.WhenAll(from m in Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
                            select PrintAsync(m));
    }
```

Where:

```
    static async Task PrintAsync(int m)
    {
        var rnd = new Random();
        await Task.Delay(rnd.Next(10));
        await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync(m.ToString());
        await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync((m+100).ToString());
    }
```

With `AsyncContext`:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       AsyncContext.Run(() => MainAsync(args));
    }
```

[image]

And without `AsyncContext` (can vary from run to run):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MainAsync(args).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
```

[image]

I could not say that understand all the mechanics here, please correct me if I am wrong.